# In InDesign, how would I get a word to move up to the line above as I have a large space open in that line?

Tags: paragraph

In InDesign, how would I get a word to move up to the line above as I have a large 
space open in that line?

Thanks, Suzanne

Answer (score 1):

Select the line and adjust the [kerning](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/indesign/cs/using/WSa285fff53dea4f8617383751001ea8cb3f-6e14a.html). Alt + Left Arrow until its on the same line. If its not going in increments of 1 you'll want to fine tune it manually.